# If a metric space $F$ is Borel isomorphic to a Lusin measurable space, then $F$ must be homeomorphic to a Borel subset of some compact metric space

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, definition, descriptive-set-theory

I'm reading about Lusin and Suslin spaces from page 46 of Dellacherie/Meyer's *Probabilities and Potential*. Here I restrict myself to metric spaces.

---

A **Borel isomorphism** between two measurable spaces is a measurable bijection whose inverse is also measurable. Let $F$ be a metric space together with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$. We denote by $F_\sigma$ (resp. $F_\delta$) the closure of $F$ under countable union (resp. intersection). Let $F_{\sigma \delta} := (F_\sigma)_\delta$. We denote by $\mathcal K (F)$ the collection of all compact subsets of $F$.

- **Def 1** A subset $A$ of $F$ is said to be **analytic** if there exists a compact metric space $E$ and $B \in (\mathcal K (E) \times \mathcal F)_{\sigma \delta}$, such that $A$ is the projection of $B$ onto $F$.
- **Def 2** $F$ is said to be **Lusin** (resp. **Suslin**, **cosuslin**) if it is homeomorphic to a Borel subset (resp. an analytic subset, the complement of an analytic subset) of a compact metric space.

Let $(X, \mathcal X)$ be a measurable space.

- **Def 3** $X$ is said to be **Lusin** (resp. **Suslin**, **cosuslin**) if it is Borel isomorphic to a measurable space $(H, \mathcal H)$ where $H$ is a Lusin (resp. Suslin, cosuslin) metric space.
- **Def 4** A subset $Y$ of $X$ is said to be **Lusin** in (resp. **Suslin**, **cosuslin**) if the measurable space $(Y, \mathcal{X}|_\mathcal Y)$ is Lusin (resp. Suslin, cosuslin).

---

**My understanding:** Let $F$ be a metric space and $\mathcal F$ its Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Suppose that $(F, \mathcal F)$ is Borel isomorphic to a Lusin measurable space $(H, \mathcal H)$. Then $F$ is Lusin by **Def 3**. To be logically consistent with **Def 2**, $F$ must be homeomorphic to a Borel subset of some compact metric space.

> Could you confirm that if a metric space $F$ is Borel isomorphic to a Lusin measurable space then $F$ must be homeomorphic to a Borel subset of some compact metric space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If a metric space is Borel isomorphic to a Borel subset of a compact metric space, then it must be separable. This follows from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1887605/21674) together with the fact that every uncountable metrizable Lusin space is isomorphic to $[0,1]$, which Dellacherie & Meyer show on page 159 in an appendix. So if $X$ is a metrizable Lusin space, it must homeomorphically embed as a subspace of the [Hilbert cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_cube) $H=[0,1]^\infty$, a compact metric space. The canonical injection $j:X\to H$ is of course measurable. Now, the image of a measurable injection from a Polish space into a Polish space is a Borel set, so $j(X)$ must be a Borel subset of $H$ and $j$ is a homeomorphism of $X$ onto a Borel subset of a metric space.

Comment: I guess you meant "If a *measurable* space is Borel isomorphic..." rather than "If a *metric* space is Borel isomorphic...".

Comment: No, I very much meant a metric space endowed with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: "If a metric space ..., it must be metrizable" sounds a little bit weird to me. Did I miss something...?

Comment: That was a typo; it should be separable...

Comment: You used that "the image of a measurable injection from a Polish space into a Polish space is a Borel set", but we do not assume that $X$ is complete. It seems to me "isomorphic" at page 159 means being Borel isomorphic.

Comment: Yes. But if $P$ is Polish and $f:X\to P$ a Borel isomorphism, then $j\circ f^{-1}$ does the job. I used this formulation because the result is easier to find in that form. The point is that you can change the topology on $X$ without changing the measurable structure.

Comment: I'm not clear why $f, P$ exist and how $j\circ f^{-1}$ does the job. The domain of $j\circ f^{-1}$ is $P$, whereas we need a homeomorphism from $X$ onto a Borel subset of some compact metric space. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: The homeomorphism is $j$. But we also have to show that $j(X)$ is a Borel subset of $H$. If $X$ is uncountable, there is a Borel isomorphism onto $[0,1]$. If $X$ countable, there is a Borel isomorphism onto $\mathbb{N}$ or a finite space. In either case, we have a Polish space $P$ and a Borel isomorphism $f:X\to P$. Now, $j(X)=j(f^{-1}(P))=(j\circ f^{-1})(P)$, the range of a measurable injection from a Polish space into a Polish space. So $j(X)$ is a Borel subset of $H$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it. It becomes clear [because](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Standard_Borel_space) a measurable space $(X, \mathcal X)$ is Borel isomorphic to some compact metric space IFF $(X, \mathcal X)$ is Borel isomorphic to some Borel subset of some compact metric space IFF $(X, \mathcal X)$ is Borel isomorphic to some Borel subset of some Polish space.